# Activity Navigation Logic

Tags: android

I have 3 Activities...the first Activity have a button that start third Activity. 
The problem is:
   When I am in 3 - rd activity press "back" button its navigate me back to 1 - st Activity, but i need to 2 - nd one. My stack of Activities always should look like : 
1. first Activity
2. second Activity
3. third Activity

How to do that ? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept the back button from Activity 3:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // start Activity 2
    return;
}
```

See [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) for more details.

Note: this only works with Android 2.0 or later.

Comment: Totally onBackPressed is the way to go if using Android 2.0+.

Answer (score 2):

If the 2nd activity is not on the stack - which it sounds like it isnt, because you went from 1st -> 3rd - which means that in your 3rd activity you will have to implement onKeyDown and capture the BACK key, and then start a new Intent with the 2nd activity.

Comment: This works obviously, but I would prefer using the `onBackPressed` method in this case.